# Applicaton.ExternalEval(String script)

Tags: unity, javascript, webgl

I was wondering, if [`Application.ExternalEval(String script);`](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Application.ExternalEval.html) in Unity3D can return something.

Like:
`String playerName = Application.ExternalEval("prompt("Please enter your name", "player1")");`

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think . But you can try to call a javacript like this (using Application.ExternalEval(.. ):

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
<!--
//initializing the WebPlayer
var u = new UnityObject2();
u.initPlugin(jQuery("#unityPlayer")[0], "Example.unity3d");

function SaySomethingToUnity()
{
    u.getUnity().SendMessage("MyObject", "MyFunction", "Hello from a web page!");
}
-->
</script>
```

who sends a message back to Unity..
check [this](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UnityWebPlayerandbrowsercommunication.html) and let me know..

Comment: So theoretically I could use `document.getElementById("someId").innerHTML += <script>..</script>;` to add a method to the document and then call it using `Application.ExternalCall("MyFunction1");` the method would respond using `u.getUnity().SendMessage("MyObject", "MyFunction", "Hello from a web page!");` - right?

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer. My first intention was to update existing answer, but then I understood that I totally rewrote it. That's why I am creating new one.

---

Yes, it's possible. The communication is possible between the browser and unity in both directions. In the [unity documentation](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UnityWebPlayerandbrowsercommunication.html) this topic is well described. So it's possible to create a general function that will allow you to call javascript code from c# and get the result of it's evaluation in c#. Just remember that it will work only in WebPlayer or WebGL, but not in Editor, since `Application.ExternalCall` and `Application.ExternalEval` will just log to the editor console in Editor.

```
public static void Evaluate(string js, System.Action<string> callback);
```

So actually you need to use callbacks here. The only catch is to store those callbacks somehow. You can do a dirty trick by using and `id` for them. And storing callbacks in a dictionary where the key is `id`. And attach this id to `js` string, so in javascript you extract id, evaluate `js` and then send result with attached `id`. And then in the c# you again extract `id` and get callback by `id` from dictionary of callbacks and call this callback on the result. Sounds creepy. So it's simple implementation will look like

```
public class JSEvaluator : MonoBehaviour {

    private int id;
    Dictionary<int, Action<string>> callbacks;

    public static void Evaluate(string js, Action<string> callback) {
        ++id;
        callbacks[id] = callback;
        // ':' is separator to know where id ends
        Application.ExternalCall("evaluate", id.ToString() + ":" + js);
    }

    private void OnJSResult(string result) {
        var stringSeparators = new string[] {":"};
        var res = source.Split(stringSeparators, StringSplitOptions.None);
        var i = Convert.ToInt32(res[0]);
        var cb = callbacks[i];
        var rem = res[0] + ":";
        cb(result.Remove(result.IndexOf(rem), rem.Length););
        callbacks.Remove(i);
    }

}
```

Several catches here. First, we increase `id`. For every `Evaluate` call. And if you make a lot of them. At some point you might experience strange results. By a lot of I mean more than 4294967296. Also we don't check of result for having `id`.

Also important thing here. `OnJSResult` is not `static`. You can't call `static` methods from javascript. Due to how `SendMessage` works. Also, `JSEvaluator` must be `MonoBehaviour`.

In javascript it would be something like.

```
function evaluate(input) {
    var inp = input.split(":");
    var id = parseInt(inp[0]);
    inp.shift();
    var arg = inp.join(":");
    var result = eval(arg);
    // for UnityPlayer you need to u.getUnity().SendMessage
    SendMessage("GameObjectName", "OnJSResult", result);
}
```

Just don't forget to create an object named `GameObjectName` on the scene and attach to it `JSEvaluator`. I think that's pretty much it. Just remember that in general this thing is not very great. But I shown you an example of communication.